# Insert next number of sequence + default values for missing lines in awk

Tags: bash, awk, pipe

I have the following table (the real file is much larger - 2gb):

**mwe.txt**

```
X   7   1   3
X   8   1   4
X   9   1   6
X   13  2   8
X   14  2   8
X   15  3   8
X   19  6   10
X   20  6   11
Y   13  2   8
Y   14  2   8
Y   15  3   8
Y   19  6   10
Y   20  6   11
```

Unfortunately if columns 3 and 4 were zero, no lines were printed for this table. I would like these missing lines inserted, with:

- "0" in columns 3 and 4
- the next sequential number after the previous row for column 2
- the name from the previous row for column 1
- a header printed, and
- line numbers added as an additional column.

I'd like to be able to pipe this, so I'd like to make it as fast as possible. I've made a start with awk, for which I found code for a similar problem:

```
awk 'BEGIN { prev_chr="";prev_pos=0;} { if($1==prev_chr && prev_pos+1!=int($2)) {for(i=prev_pos+1;i<int($2);++i) {printf("%s\t%d\t0\n",$1,i);}} print; prev_chr=$1;prev_pos=int($2);}' mwe.txt > output.txt
```

which outputs the following:

**output.txt**

```
X   7   1   3
X   8   1   4
X   9   1   6
X   10  0
X   11  0
X   12  0
X   13  2   8
X   14  2   8
X   15  3   8
X   16  0
X   17  0
X   18  0
X   19  6   10
X   20  6   11
Y   13  2   8
Y   14  2   8
Y   15  3   8
Y   16  0
Y   17  0
Y   18  0
Y   19  6   10
Y   20  6   11
```

As you can see, it does not put zeros into column 4 for the missing lines.

In short, the desired output:

```
mCoord  chr coord   samp1   samp2
1   X   7   1   3
2   X   8   1   4
3   X   9   1   6
4   X   10  0   0
5   X   11  0   0
6   X   12  0   0
7   X   13  2   8
8   X   14  2   8
9   X   15  3   8
10  X   16  0   0
11  X   17  0   0
12  X   18  0   0
13  X   19  6   10
14  X   20  6   11
15  Y   13  2   8
16  Y   14  2   8
17  Y   15  3   8
18  Y   16  0   0
19  Y   17  0   0
20  Y   18  0   0
21  Y   19  6   10
22  Y   20  6   11
```

Comment: It's a minor change, learn what the code you're using does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `awk` solution:

```
awk 'NR>1 && $2!=exp_idx{
         for (i=exp_idx;i<$2;i++){
            printf("%d  %s   %d  0   0\n",++cont,exp_coord,i)
         }

     }
     {print ++cont"  "$0;exp_coord=$1;exp_idx=$2+1}
    ' input
```

**Results**

```
1  X   7   1   3
2  X   8   1   4
3  X   9   1   6
4  X   10  0   0
5  X   11  0   0
6  X   12  0   0
7  X   13  2   8
8  X   14  2   8
9  X   15  3   8
10  X   16  0   0
11  X   17  0   0
12  X   18  0   0
13  X   19  6   10
14  X   20  6   11
15  Y   13  2   8
16  Y   14  2   8
17  Y   15  3   8
18  Y   16  0   0
19  Y   17  0   0
20  Y   18  0   0
21  Y   19  6   10
22  Y   20  6   11
```

Comment: Some adjustments to get the exact desired output: 
`awk 'BEGIN {print "mCoord\tchr\tcoord\tsamp1\tsamp2";} NR>1 && $2!=exp_idx{for (i=exp_idx;i<$2;i++){printf("%d\t%s\t%d\t0\t0\n",++cont,exp_coord,i)}}{print ++cont"\t"$0;exp_coord=$1;exp_idx=$2+1}' mwe.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Perl solution:

```
perl -lpae '@p =@ F, next if 1 == $.;
            print "$p[0]   $_   0   0" for $p[1] + 1 .. $F[1] - 1;
            @p = @F
           ' input > output
```

It just remembers the previous line's columns in @p.